# @ConfigurationProperties not binding properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have the following Configuration CLass:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import lombok.Data;


@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail.config")
@Data
@RefreshScope
@Validated
public class MailboxPropertiesConfiguration{
    
    @NotBlank
    private String host;

    @NotBlank
    private String adminLogin;

    @NotBlank
    private String adminPassword;

}
```

and the following properties file:

```
mail.config.host=127.0.0.1
mail.config.admin-login=xxx
mail.config.admin-password=yyy
```

And the following class:

```java
@Configuration
public class MailboxProducer extends AbstractConfiguration{

    protected MailboxProducer(MailboxPropertiesConfiguration config) {
        super(config.getHost());
    }
    
}
```

My issue is that `config.getHost()` is null (so are the other properties) even though I have the setters (`@Data`)
I tried removing `@ConfigurationProperties` and use `@Value` instead but I have the same result.
Could you please let me know what am I doing wrong?

thanks.
(I'm using Spring boot 2.4.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `@Configuration` from `MailboxPropertiesConfiguration`.
2. Add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MailboxPropertiesConfiguration.class)` to `MailboxProducer`